# MvvmCross WPF - Multi-window application (MvxWindow)

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvmcross, multi-window

I have verified a lot of samples 'how to' create WPF apps using MvvmCross framework. But there is no showing how to create a multi-window application.

How can I create and show independent window with own ViewModel?

My project files looks like:

MainWindow.xaml => MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow : MvxWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

LoginPageView.xaml => LoginPageView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class LoginPageView : MvxWpfView
{
    public LoginPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MenuPageView.xaml => MenuPageView.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MenuPageView : MvxWindow // <-- I want use UserControl (MvxWpfView), and Window (MvxWindow)
{
    public MenuPageView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

When I use MvxWindow class for MenuPageView, there is exception such as below.

```
mvx: Diagnostic: 11,83 Showing ViewModel MenuPageViewModel
mvx: Error: 11,84 Error seen during navigation request to MenuPageViewModel - error InvalidOperationException: Window must be the root element of the tree. The Window element can not be added as a child element of Visual.
in System.Windows.Window.OnAncestorChanged ()
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnAncestorChangedInternal (TreeChangeInfo parentTreeState)
   in System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.OnAncestorChanged (DependencyObject d, TreeChangeInfo info, Boolean visitedViaVisualTree)
   in System.Windows.DescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk (DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   in MS.Internal.PrePostDescendentsWalker`1.StartWalk (DependencyObject startNode, Boolean skipStartNode)
   in System.Windows.TreeWalkHelper.InvalidateOnTreeChange (FrameworkElement fe, FrameworkContentElement fce, DependencyObject parent, Boolean isAddOperation)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.ChangeLogicalParent (DependencyObject newParent)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.AddLogicalChild (Object child)
   in System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged (Object oldContent, Object newContent)
   in System.Windows.Window.OnContentChanged (Object oldContent, Object newContent)
   in System.Windows.Controls.ContentControl.OnContentChanged (DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
   in System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange (DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
   in System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue (EntryIndex entryIndex, DependencyProperty dp, PropertyMetadata metadata, EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, EffectiveValueEntry & newEntry, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType)
   in System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon (DependencyProperty dp, Object value, PropertyMetadata metadata, Boolean coerceWithDeferredReference, Boolean coerceWithCurrentValue, OperationType operationType, Boolean isInternal)
   in System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue (DependencyProperty dp, Object value)
   in MvvmCross.Wpf.Views.Presenters.MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter.Present (FrameworkElement frameworkElement) in D: \ git \ MvvmCross \ MvvmCross \ Windows \ Wpf \ Views \ Presenters \ MvxSimpleWpfViewPresenter.cs: line 41
   in MvvmCross.Wpf.Views.Presenters.MvxBaseWpfViewPresenter.Show (MvxViewModelRequest request) in D: \ git \ MvvmCross \ MvvmCross \ Windows \ Wpf \ Views \ Presenters \ MvxBaseWpfViewPresenter.cs: line 27
```

Comment: Each window would need it's own control, even if you only intend to use one (user control).  You would then need to adapt the default navigation to detect whether a given Window was open and, if not, create it

Comment: Can you provide the sample. I know that it's easy to hear but practically it does not look like working.

Comment: Can you post your navigation code, please?

Comment: I use default navigation of MVVM Cross. It looks like:

ShowViewModel<MenuPageViewModel>();

Comment: I think there's an example of this in the MVVM source, under Playground: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/tree/master/Projects/Playground